# How to iterate items into rows divided by 3 columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you will see in my JSFiddle link at the end of this post, I have a dropdown menu that filters items into categories. I have every item stored as objects in an array for each category. As of right now, everything is displayed in one column. I want to be able to count how many items that will be displayed for each category and then divide that by 3 in order to get how many will go in each column.

I'm thinking I'll need to use a for loop to count up to that number while putting the items in the first column, and when that loop finishes, I will have to do that for each column. The loops would be nested... the outer loop would say something like start a new row and the inner loop inserts the correct number of items... Does that make sense? I feel like it does, but the problem is that I have no idea how to do that. I'm a jQuery noob, let alone web programming.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! Please and thank you!

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button id="division-select" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-target=".nav-collapse">Categories<span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul id="filterOptions" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li id="get_cats"><a href="#" class="cats">Cats</a></li>
    <li id="get_dogs"><a href="#" class="dogs">Dogs</a></li>
    <li id="get_birds"><a href="#" class="birds">Birds</a></li>
    <li id="get_all"><a href="#" class="everything">Everything</a></li>
   </ul>
</div> <!-- .btn-group -->  

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <a id="cats"></a>
        <a id="dogs"></a>
        <a id="birds"></a>  
        <a id="everything"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var data={
    "cats":[
        {"breed":"bengal"},
        {"breed":"savannah"},
        {"breed":"ragdoll"},
        {"breed":"munchkin"},
        {"breed":"siamese"}
    ],
    "dogs":[
        {"breed":"german shepherd"},
        {"breed":"jack russell terrier"}
    ],
    "birds":[
        {"breed":"parrot"}
    ],
    "everything":[
        {"breed":"bengal"},
        {"breed":"savannah"},
        {"breed":"ragdoll"},
        {"breed":"munchkin"},
        {"breed":"siamese"},
        {"breed":"german shepherd"},
        {"breed":"jack russell terrier"},
        {"breed":"parrot"}
    ]
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    everything();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#get_cats").click(
        function () {
            cats();
        }   
    );   
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#get_dogs").click(
        function () {
            dogs();
        }  
    );   
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#get_birds").click(
        function () {
            birds();
        }   
    );   
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#get_all").click(
        function () {
            everything();
        }  
    );   
});

function cats() {
    document.getElementById("dogs").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("birds").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("everything").innerHTML=""; 
    var output="<div class='text-center'>";
    for (var i in data.cats) {
        output += "<a class='thumbnail'><h3>"+ data.cats[i].breed +"</h3></a>";
    }
    output+="</div>";
    document.getElementById("cats").innerHTML=output; 
}

function dogs() {
    document.getElementById("cats").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("birds").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("everything").innerHTML=""; 
    var output="<div class='text-center'>";
    for (var i in data.dogs) {
        output += "<a class='thumbnail'><h3>"+ data.dogs[i].breed +"</h3></a>";
    }
    output+="</div>";
    document.getElementById("dogs").innerHTML=output; 
}

function birds() {
    document.getElementById("dogs").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("cats").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("everything").innerHTML=""; 
    var output="<div class='text-center'>";
    for (var i in data.birds) {
        output += "<a class='thumbnail'><h3>"+ data.birds[i].breed +"</h3></a>";
    }
    output+="</div>";
    document.getElementById("birds").innerHTML=output; 
}

function everything() {
    document.getElementById("dogs").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("birds").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("cats").innerHTML="";   
    var output="<div class='text-center'>";
    for (var i in data.everything) {
        output += "<a class='thumbnail'><h3>"+ data.everything[i].breed +"</h3></a>";
    }
    output+="</div>";
    document.getElementById("everything").innerHTML=output; 
}
```

[image: How I want it to look]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZ63R/6/)

Comment: I want to be able to count how many items that will be displayed for each category and then divide that by 3 in order to get how many will go in each column. 

http://jsfiddle.net/pragneshkaria/BZ63R/4/

 Hope this answers your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to show the sub categories in three columns instead of one column?

If yes , then you can simply do it by CSS , no need of java script.

```
<a id="everything"><div class="text-center"><a class="thumbnail"><h3>bengal</h3></a><a class="thumbnail"><h3>savannah</h3></a><a class="thumbnail"><h3>ragdoll</h3></a><a class="thumbnail"><h3>munchkin</h3></a><a class="thumbnail"><h3>siamese</h3></a><a class="thumbnail"><h3>german shepherd</h3></a><a class="thumbnail"><h3>jack russell terrier</h3></a><a class="thumbnail"><h3>parrot</h3></a></div></a>
```

Instead of using  use UL > LI , provide 33% width to LI and float:left;

Hope this will solve your question.
You can also use , CSS on .thumnail class.

Note : Your fiddle link doesn't give any output.

```
.thumbnail {
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    margin:4px;
}
.thumbnail h3 {
    min-height:80px;
}
```

use this link  : http://jsfiddle.net/pragneshkaria/BZ63R/4/

Comment: Wow, I am amazed. I truly thought the only way of doing this would be with javascript. Thank you so much, my only question is, how would I get the items to all float with equal distance in each direction? Sorry, I don't know how to explain this well, but check out how it looks with the css you suggested --> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZ63R/5/) notice how the bottom row is not floating right underneath the second row?

Comment: Also, thanks for letting me know about the messed up link, I guess I forgot to update it. I just edited it with the right link

Comment: can you please draw a rough picture and upload that image , to show us , what you actually want?

Comment: of course, I just edited my post by adding an image. Notice how the space between each row is the same? If possible, that is what I need it to look like. Thank you